# Export and Import XWiki Pages via REST API

Tags: xwiki

XWiki has the ability to export pages in a XAR format via the Administration application so it can then be imported into another XWiki instance.

Is this possible to do via the REST API?

Answer (score 1):

It's not done via the REST API. See https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/UserGuide/Features/Exports#HAdvanced